# HTML Doesn't use NGINX redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx

Nginx Config

```
 location /mysite {
        proxy_pass https://mysite;
    }
```

in the html:

```
<a href="/mysite">test</a>
```

When the link is clicked it goes to /mysite and doesn'y use the proxy_pass. Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you want a redirect, or do you want to proxy the result? These are completely different things.

Comment: If you are looking to go mysite then change `proxy_pass` to `return 301 https://mysite;`

Comment: There's no way to just query the location uri -> proxy_pass url and use it I assume. 

I'm trying to limit the # of places I'm hard coding some URLs. Looks like I need 2 at a minimum, one to do a proxy_pass and another to do the redirect.